# eBPF Program Not Capturing Syscall Argument

Tags: ebpf

I have the following eBPF program configured to get information about `openat` calls.

```
from bcc import BPF
from bcc.utils import printb
import sys

BPF_SOURCE_CODE = r"""
BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(events);

#define MAX_FILENAME 100

struct data_t {
  int dirfd;
  int flags;
  int mode;
  char filename[MAX_FILENAME+1];
};

TRACEPOINT_PROBE(syscalls, sys_enter_openat) {
   struct data_t data = {};

   data.dirfd = args->dfd;
   data.flags = args->flags;
   data.mode = args->mode;

   bpf_probe_read_user(&data.filename, sizeof(data.filename), args->filename);

   events.perf_submit(args, &data, sizeof(data));

   return 0;
}
"""

bpf = BPF(text = BPF_SOURCE_CODE)

def handle_event(cpu, data, size):
    output = bpf["events"].event(data)
    print(output.filename)

bpf["events"].open_perf_buffer(handle_event)

while True:
    try:
        bpf.perf_buffer_poll()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        sys.exit(0)
```

I wrote the following test program to verify that the eBPF program works correctly.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int fd;
  fd = open("/tmp/test.txt", O_RDONLY);  
  fd = open("/tmp/test1.txt", O_RDONLY);
  fd = open("/tmp/test2.txt", O_RDONLY);  
}
```

The eBPF program reliably captures the filenames for the second and third `open` calls, but never captures the filename for the first call:

```
$ sudo python3 listen.py
<-- snip -->
b''
b'/tmp/test1.txt'
b'/tmp/test2.txt'
```

Any ideas on why the eBPF program isn't getting information about the filename for the first `open` call?

Comment: Did you strace it to confirm that the openat syscall is made with the expected arguments?

Comment: Good thought - I had inspected the binary's disassembly to make sure it was making the call as expected, but I hadn't strace'd it. Just strace'd it now, and `openat` is being called. Curiously, eBPF sees the first call to `openat` when the program is being strace'd.